# How to change error message when user is not authorised for elmah?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elmah, elmah.mvc

[image]

I do not want to show this error message when use is not authorized / on remote machine. I want to show my custom error message. I am using elmah for error logging.

**my app setting**

```
<add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandler" value="false" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandleErrorFilter" value="false" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.requiresAuthentication" value="false" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.IgnoreDefaultRoute" value="false" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.allowedRoles" value="*" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.allowedUsers" value="*" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.route" value="elmah" />
<add key="elmah.mvc.UserAuthCaseSensitive" value="true" />
```

How I can change this page / message ?

Answer (score 0):

Set `disableHandleErrorFilter` to true:

```
<add key="elmah.mvc.disableHandleErrorFilter" value="true" />
```

Comment out the the global filter config for the following within `FilterConfig`:

```
//filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
```

Comment: What is it doing now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94351/discussion-between-kaushik-thanki-and-coulton).